# JSON parse javascript string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Trying to parse the json string with JSON.parse I get unexpected token error

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
url = URI.parse("https://url-goes-here")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
req['Accept'] = 'application/json'
res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
    http.request(req)
end
json = JSON.parse(res)
puts json
```

Comment: JSON::ParserError: 765: unexpected token at 'jQuery18307882644047005491_1545806199753({"success":true,"code":0,"results":[{"productId":32817749905,"sellerId":228928782,"oriMinPrice":"US $363.00","oriMaxPrice":"US $507.10","promotionId":317767132,"startTime":1545638400,"endTime":1546070340,"phase":1,"productTitle":"Top quality ... Do you need to see the whole string?

Comment: That's not JSON, it looks more like a JS function call.

Comment: The remote site uses Struts framework, javascript files with an added .do extension What type of data is it and how do I parse it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by the above code are doing some functionality like scraping.

Comment: Yes I'm scraping

Answer (score 0):

Data in response looks like JSONP, rather old method of doing rpc. Instead of returning plain JSON it outputs `some_js_callback_function_name({here_goes: the_json})`, usually there's also a parameter that controls the function name.

To get json from it - trim the function call before parsing:

```
json_data = res.body.gsub(/\A[^(]+\(/, '').gsub(/\)\s*\z/, '')
json = JSON.parse(json_data)
```

Comment: This may be due to white space after `)`. Try replacing `.chop` with `.gsub(/\)\s*\z/, '')`

Comment: @stuckonrails that's syntax error in your regex (unescaped `(`), the idea is to strip everything from the beginning up to the first `(` (any char except for `(` plus bracket itself) and the trailing bracket along with any space after it